# Find first and second order contacts of each node in a network

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I have a graph having 602647 nodes and 982982 edges. I wanted to find the first and second order contacts (i.e. 1-hop contacts and 2-hops contacts) for each node in the graph in Networkx.

i built the following code that worked fine for smaller graphs, but never finished running for larger (graphs as the one above):

```
hop_1 = {}
hop_2 = {}
row_1 = {}
row_2 = {}

for u, g in G.nodes(data=True):
    row_1.setdefault(u, nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, u, cutoff=1))
    row_2.setdefault(u, nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, u, cutoff=2))
    hop_1.update(row_1)
    hop_2.update(row_2)
```

some notes:

- results are stored first in a dict (hope_1 and hope_2)
- row_1 and row_2 and temporary holding variables
- hop-1 will include nodes after one jump
- hop-2 will include nodes that are located at both one jump and two jumps

Is there a way to optimize/imrpove this code and finish running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `networkx`; but, by definition, a node that is reachable one hop is also reachable in <=2 hops, which is what the [docs (and source) of `single_source_shortest_path_length`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path_length.html) is giving you.  you can therefore remove the first call to `single_source_shortest_path_length`.

second, your uses of dictionaries are **very** strange!  why are you using `setdefault` rather than just setting elements?  also you're copying things a lot with `update` which doesn't do anything useful and just wastes time.

I'd do something like:

```
hop_1 = {}
hop_2 = {}

for u in G.nodes():
    d1 = []
    d2 = []
    for v, n in nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G, u, cutoff=2).items():
        if n == 1:
            d1.append(v)
        elif n == 2:
            d2.append(v)
    hop_1[u] = d1
    hop_2[u] = d2
```

which takes about a minute on my laptop with a `G_nm` graph as generated by:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(602647, 982982)
```

note that [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is nice for showing progress of long running loops, just `import tqdm` and change the outer `for` loop to be:

```
for u in tqdm(G.nodes()):
   ...
```

and you'll get a nice bar reporting progress

Comment: @Taie no probs!  was just trying to replicate your deleted comment, but it always seemed correct to me...

Answer (score 2):

To find first and second-order neighbors you can use functions `all_neighbors()` and `node_boundary()`:

[image]

```
hop1 = {}
hop2 = {}

for n in G.nodes():
    neighbs1 = list(nx.all_neighbors(G, n))
    hop1[n] = neighbs1
    hop2[n] = list(nx.node_boundary(G, neighbs1 + [n])) + neighbs1

print(hop1)
# {0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 3, 4], 3: [0, 1, 2, 4], 4: [2, 3]}
print(hop2)
# {0: [4, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 0, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 3, 4], 3: [0, 1, 2, 4], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```